# How to reset an object int value when an intermediate element is remove from list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I got a list with objects that have an attribute "serie" that save the order of elements:

```
---------------------------------
| **Element**       |**Serie**  |
---------------------------------
| Object1           |     1     |
---------------------------------
| Object2           |     2     |
---------------------------------
| Object3           |     3     |
---------------------------------
```

How can i get that, if i remove element 2, the atribute serie of my object 3 change to 2, i meant, reset the value of serie of all the elements after the element removed.

Any help will be much apreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to manually loop over the list and modify the property of the objects, setting its value on each item to be equal to the item's index.

If you know the index of the object that was removed then you can start looping from that point onwards, since nothing will have changed for the objects that come earlier.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    public class Object
    {
        public int Serie;
    }
```

Then:

```
       var list = new List<Object>();
       list.Add(new Object { Serie = 1 });
       list.Add(new Object { Serie = 2 });
       list.Add(new Object { Serie = 3 });

       list.RemoveAt(1);

       int i = 1;
       foreach (Object obj in list)
       {
           obj.Serie = i;
           i++;
       }
```